# How to get all images inside a folder with MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, directory, file-extension

If I knew the extension of images (`.jpg` for example), then I would use the following to list all images:

```
images = dir([myfolder '\*.jpg']);
```

But what if I don't know the extension, and want it to work for a given set of extensions (let's say `jpg`, `png` and `bmp`). How can I do a generic function that takes a folder path as input and returns all the images with these extensions?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Use the above marked duplicate as a start. The duplicate only does it for two types of images though. Simply do another `dir` call for the third type and concatenate all of the file names into a single structure like what was done with just two types.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `dir()` returns you a struct, you can just concatenate them together:

```
images = [dir('*.jpg'); dir('*.png'); dir('*.bmp')];
```